# Remove using temporary and Filesort from query execution

Tags: mysql, group-by, partitioning, temp-tables, filesort

I have one table having almost 90 columns and also using Range Partition on it. This table has almost 50lacs records. When I used `GROUP BY` in Query at that time it shows "using temporary" and "filesort" in explain statement.

Query :

```
 SELECT
 subscribe_time * 0.000001 AS start_date,
 subscribe_time * 0.000001 AS end_date,
 (
    IFNULL(
      ROUND(
         SUM(
          CASE WHEN(
              subscribe_duration > 20000 AND subscribe_status = '1'
              ) THEN 1 ELSE 0
          END
          ) /(
            SUM(
              CASE WHEN(subscribe_status = '1') THEN 1 ELSE 0
              END
           )
      ) * 100,
    2
  ),
  0
)
) AS subscribe_avg

FROM
  tbl_subscription a
WHERE
  1 AND subscribe_time > 0 AND subscribe_time BETWEEN "1525113000000000" AND "1524680999999999"
GROUP BY
  EXTRACT(
    YEAR
    FROM
       FROM_UNIXTIME(subscribe_time * 0.000001)
    ),
  EXTRACT(
    MONTH
    FROM
    FROM_UNIXTIME(subscribe_time * 0.000001)
  ),
  EXTRACT(
     WEEK
     FROM
     FROM_UNIXTIME(subscribe_time * 0.000001)
 ),
 EXTRACT(
   DAY
   FROM
   FROM_UNIXTIME(subscribe_time * 0.000001)
),
sub_user,
subscribe_ip,
subscribe_zone,
subscribe_approval
```

Indexing is already given on field1. field1 is not our PK. On total 5 columns indexing are given.

When I write `GROUP BY` query took almost 43sec to execute. and When I remove `GROUP BY` at that time it is taking 0.27sec execution time.

Also when we write "`ORDER BY NULL`" at last then filesort is removed. But I don't want to use `ORDER BY` in my query.
How to reduce query execution time?

Also, I tried to fetch data from a single partition also, but still query is taking the same time. Query to fetch data from single partition :

```
 SELECT field1, field2 FROM TABLE_NAME PARTITION(p1) WHERE 1 AND 
   field1='SOME_VALUE' GROUP BY field1;
```

Give some suggestions to reduce query execution time.

Comment: Your first query makes no sense to me.  Why are you grouping by `field1` if you restrict it only one value?  Also, selecting `field2` in that query is most likely invalid (though it _might_ run, sadly, in MySQL).  Please add a problem statement to your question, and some sample data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I am doing arithmetic operations in SELECT Statement, that is the reason for using GROUP BY. My actual query has some arithmetic operations but those I have not listed here.

Comment: Then I recommend that you show us the real problem.

Comment: Put your example here https://www.db-fiddle.com/ and publish it.

Comment: Added my query in Actual question. Actually, GROUP BY columns are too many.

Comment: Now that the query does not have `field1`, please edit the rest of the question!

Comment: @Khushal - The number of expressions in `GROUP BY` is not critical.  Various things prevent use of an index; in this case the expression.

Answer (score 0):

The first expression of the `GROUP BY` can probably be replaced by

```
subscribe_time
```

or perhaps

```
FLOOR(subscribe_time * 0.000001)
```

I see no need to break it apart just to do the `GROUP BY`.

Can you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`? - We need to see indexes, partitioning, and probably other details.  In particular, does it have either or both of

```
PARTITION BY RANGE(subscribe_time)
INDEX(subscribe_time)
```